# Redirect all subdomains path with apache to another subdomain

Tags: apache, redirect

Today I'd like to redirect all the paths of a subdomain that I created to another subdomain withing my private server, but I'd like to do it with APACHE instead of using the WHM.

This is what I'd like to obtain:
I want to redirect (forward) all these subdomains:

```
mysubdomain.mydomain.com/
mysubdomain.mydomain.com/path/
mysubdomain.mydomain.com/path/anotherpath/
```

to

```
myothersubdomain.mydomain.com/
```

I tried:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^mysubdomain.mydomain.com/path/anotherpath/ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myothersubdomain.mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysubdomain.mydomain.com/path/anotherpath/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myothersubdomain.mydomain.com/$1

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysubdomain.mydomain.com/path/anotherpath/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ myothersubdomain.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Do I need a sort of wildcard at the end of my first subdomain?

UPDATE:

With all those snippets nothing has happened. I want that my user will be redirected from:

**mysubdomain.mydomain.com/path/anotherpath/**

to

**myothersubdomain.mydomain.com/**

when he/she'll click the link **mysubdomain.mydomain.com/path/anotherpath/**. At the moment the final user can still see the content of **mysubdomain.mydomain.com/path/anotherpath/**.

Comment: You point out what you tried, but not what the result of the try was and how that result differed from your expected result. That would be helpful to understand your problem.

Comment: The problem is that nothing happened. I'm gonna add this information to explain what the problem was.